# Python EBNF how to read

Tags: python, grammar, ebnf

So I came across the grammar for the Python language (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) and I cannot fully understand how it works. Especially, I'm interested in this snipped about if statements.

```
if_stmt: 'if' namedexpr_test ':' suite ('elif' namedexpr_test ':' suite)* ['else' ':' suite]
[...]
namedexpr_test: test [':=' test]
test: or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test] | lambdef
test_nocond: or_test | lambdef_nocond
lambdef: 'lambda' [varargslist] ':' test
lambdef_nocond: 'lambda' [varargslist] ':' test_nocond
or_test: and_test ('or' and_test)*
and_test: not_test ('and' not_test)*
not_test: 'not' not_test | comparison
comparison: expr (comp_op expr)*
# <> isn't actually a valid comparison operator in Python. It's here for the
# sake of a __future__ import described in PEP 401 (which really works :-)
comp_op: '<'|'>'|'=='|'>='|'<='|'<>'|'!='|'in'|'not' 'in'|'is'|'is' 'not'
```

There is a certain style here.  Defining `or_test` in terms of `and_test` and `and_test` again in terms of `not_test`. What is the advantage of this style? (Because I saw it used also in the grammar for C++, and most likely many other languages too).

Comment: This is so `and` has higher precedence than `or`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It encodes precedence. With this grammar, you can unambiguously parse the expression

```
not x and y or z
```

as

```
                    or_test
                   /       \
                  /         z
                and_test
               /        \
              /          y
          not_test
             |
             x
```

in the "expected" manner, without needing parentheses.